# Не добавлять второй тег ZAP, если уже есть у пациента

Tags: java, xml

Есть метод, который парсит `XML` файл и создает другой со следующей структурой:
`ZAP` содержит теги `patient, sluch, usl`. Каждый тег `ZAP` описывает данные пациента и тегов `sluch` может быть у одного пациента несколько.

Нужно если в исходном файле несколько строк row, у которых один и тот же полис не создавая новый тег `ZAP` добавить в существующий новый случай `sluch`.

У меня это получилось, но не могу понять как НЕ создавать при этом тег `zap` второй раз для одного и того же пациента

```
private static List<Zap> getZapList() {

    List<Row> rowsList = ReadXmlDs.getRowsForXMLDS("C:\\ds_parse\\ds.xml");

    List<Zap> zapList = new ArrayList<>();

    for (int i = 0; i < rowsList.size(); i++) {

        for (Zap zap : zapList) {
            //Если в списке zapList есть такой же полис как в rowsList.get(i).getNpolis()
            if (zap.getPacient().getNpolis().equals(rowsList.get(i).getNpolis())) {

                //То создаем случаи и услуги
                Sluch sluch = createSluch(rowsList.get(i));

                Usl usl = createUsl(rowsList.get(i), sluch);

                createCrit(rowsList.get(i), usl);
                createHrrgd(rowsList.get(i), usl);

                sluch.setUsl(usl);

                zap.getSluchList().add(sluch);
            }
        }

        Zap zap = new Zap();

        Pacient pacient = createPatient(rowsList.get(i));

        Sluch sluch = createSluch(rowsList.get(i));

        Usl usl = createUsl(rowsList.get(i), sluch);

        createCrit(rowsList.get(i), usl);
        createHrrgd(rowsList.get(i), usl);

        sluch.setUsl(usl);

        zap.setPacient(pacient);

        List<Sluch> sluchList = new ArrayList<>();
        sluchList.add(sluch);

        zap.setSluchList(sluchList);

        zapList.add(zap);
    }

    return zapList;
}
```

Comment: Немного переделала метод, чтобы проще было понять что происходит

Answer (score 0):

Не стоит буквально понимать названия переменных :) Ну и что, что  sluchList. Используйте Set вместо List и будет вам счастье без лишнего кода и повторений.

```java
        Set<Sluch> sluchList = new LinkedHashSet<>();
        sluchList.add(sluch);
```

Потом, если в целевой структуре требуется List, то можно сделать так

```java
 zap.setSluchList(new ArrayList<Sluch>(sluchList));
```

Comment: Может я неправильно объяснила или неправильно поняла ваш ответ. Дело в том, что несколько записей row могут принадлежать одному пациенту и нужно их них сделать один сегмент zap, внутри которой несколько sluch. У меня пока получилось сделать так в zap добавить все sluch, но при этом еще создается второй zap сегмент для второй строки row. Т.е. если в rowList две строки принадлежащие одному пациенту, то создается первый zap со всеми sluch из всех row, далее еще создаются zap для остальных row. А мне нужно чтобы дополнительные zap для него не создавались.

Comment: Переделала по вашему совету тоже самое как и у меня.

Comment: Сделала так: Optional<Zap> zapOptional = zapList.stream().filter(z->z.getPacient().getNpolis().equals(zap.getPacient().getNpolis())).findFirst();

if (zapOptional.isPresent()) {
} else {
 zapList.add(zap);
}.  Буду тестировать)